# How to POST data to a server in Sencha Touch without using AJAX

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am using Sencha Touch, I need post some data to a Server with a simple HTTP POST (NO AJAX)

At the moment I use

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request

Ext.Ajax.request
```

for my understanding both work with AJAX.

I would like to know how to disable the AJAX functionality and allow me to send some paramenters only via HTTP without using xhr and ajax.

Comment: `document.location.href = 'http://www.example.com/mypage?q=query'`? Is there a good reason not to use AJAX?

Comment: thanks for your comment, I need it in sencha touch

Comment: Do'h I'm sorry. I was looking at the `extjs` tag ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a form panel and then call the `submit` method with a url for the form to be submitted to:

```
// define your form
var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
  ...
  // your form fields, etc
});

// later, in some handler for a button click, etc
form.submit({
  url: 'url/to/submit.php',
  method: 'POST',
  success: function() {
    // handle successful form submit
  },
  failure: funciton() { ... }
});
```